# Relations between two united sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given two sets $A$ and $B$.

What can we say about the relation between $A$ and $B$, if $A \cup B \subset A$?

I would say that in this case, $B$ must be a subset of $A$. But equality would also be possible, or not?

Comment: $B$ is a subset of $A$ for sure but if you are writing $\subset$ for proper subsert then $B$ cannot be equal to $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are completely correct. We know that $ B\subset A\cup B $, so we have $ B\subset A $. And, if $ A = B $ then we still satisfy $ A\cup B\subset A $.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But A = B must not be the case, this is only a "special" case, right?

Answer (score 1):

You have $A\subset A\cup B\subset A\iff A\cup B=A\iff B\subset A$